# Bind the frequencies of two observations in r

Tags: r

I've two observations and my aim is to bind the frequency counts together so I can perform e.g. a chi-square test.

```
a <- c(1,1,5,6,3,6,1,5,5,1,2,5,2,1,3,3,6,5,7,4)
b <- c(1,5,4,4,1,5,4,4,2,1,2,1,2)
> table(a)
a
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
5 2 3 1 5 3 1
> table(b)
b
1 2 4 5 
4 3 4 2
```

As the print shows, the second observation lacks observations for the factors 3,6 and 7. Hence I can't bind them using `cbind(table(a), table(b))`. As this results in:

```
 > cbind(table(a), table(b))
   [,1] [,2]
 1    5    4
 2    2    3
 3    3    4
 4    1    2
 5    5    4
 6    3    3
 7    1    4
 Warning message:
 In cbind(table(a), table(b)) :
   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

I was wondering about appropriate methods to combine the observations to get a result similar to this:

```
   [,1] [,2]
 1    5    4
 2    2    3
 3    3    0
 4    1    4
 5    5    2
 6    3    0
 7    1    0
```

Comment: Try using `tabulate` instead of `table`. Set the `nbins` argument to 7. `cbind(tabulate(a,nbins=7),tabulate(b,nbins=7))`

Comment: You might consider storing your data in a single object (`stack(list(a = a, b = b))`) where you can use `table(stack(list(a = a, b = b)))`.

Comment: Merci mille! Every answer provided has it's own advantage in terms of elegance, efficiency and comprehension. However as I can accept only one answer I chose the one with the most upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `sort`ed `union` of both `vector`s, get the frequency of each `vector` (`table`) and `cbind` it

```
un1 <-  sort(union(a,b))
cbind(table(factor(a, levels = un1)), table(factor(b, levels = un1)))
#   [,1] [,2]
#1    5    4
#2    2    3
#3    3    0
#4    1    4
#5    5    2
#6    3    0
#7    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
df <- merge(table(a), table(b), by.x='a', by.y='b', all=TRUE)[-1]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
#    Freq.x Freq.y
#1      5      4
#2      2      3
#3      3      0
#4      1      4
#5      5      2
#6      3      0
#7      1      0
```

Comment: `as.data.frame` are not necessary.  It happens internally.  Edited.